# Is it possible to post to chat.postMessage as any user in a Slack team?

Tags: javascript, slack-api, slack

I'm building a Slack integration that is intended to modify some text and then post it to a Slack channel as though the user who triggered the command had said it.

e.g. `/makeFace disapproval`

`@Ben 3:45pm
 ಠ_ಠ`

I ask for the `client` permission scope, which adds the `chat:write:user` permission. But when I hit the `chat.postMessage` endpoint, it only seems to allow you to post *as the user who added the integration* because the token it returns seems to be individuated for that user.

I know that giphy, for instance, sends its gif messages as though you are the originator, but I can't find out how they manage it. Is there any documentation for sending messages as other members of the team?

Comment: @Erik has a good answer, but still good to mention that the Giphy integration was built by Slack, and therefore enjoys special privileges :D

Comment: That's what I was thinking, too!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are 2 ways to achieve this:

**A. Overwriting username and icon**

When you send a message with [`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) it is possible to set a user name with the property `username`. The message will then appear as being send by that user (same for icon with `icon_url`).

However, this is not meant to impersonate real users, so even if you use the same username and icon as the real user the message will have the app tag, so that they can be distinguished from a real user.

Here is an example how it looks like (from a gamer Slack about flying and killing space ships):
[image]

But depending on what your requirements are that might work for you.

If you want to use it make sure to also set the `as_user` property to `false` (yes, really) and it will not work with a bot token, only with a user token.

See [here](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#authorship) for more details on how it works.

This also works for the legacy version of [Incoming Webhooks](https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/incoming-webhooks), not with the current version of [incoming webhooks](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks) though. (You can still get the legacy version, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51952974/4379151))

**B. Having the user's token**

Another approach is to always use the token from the respective user for sending the message. In combination with `as_user = true` messages sent by your app will look exactly as if they would come from the respective user (no `APP` tag).

To make that happen your app would need to collect tokens from all users on your workspace and store them for later use. This can be done by asking every user to install your app (called adding a "configuration") through the [Oauth process](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth) (same you use to install your app to a workspace), which allows your app to collect and store those tokens for later use.

Comment: This is a way of doing it, but worth pointing out that Slack has said they want to restrict this functionality of changing the picture on every request. (Although they did say that over a year ago)

Comment: Thanks. The documentation is incredibly vague about this!

Comment: Hi !
I am trying to do the same as solution B, but after a lot of doc reading and code trying, I am starting to think that it is not possible anymore. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, you're right. V Maharajh's answer is now the correct one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42658126/is-it-possible-to-post-to-chat-postmessage-as-any-user-in-a-slack-team/70103904#70103904

Answer (score 3):

**Update: This doesn't work. It impersonates the user who installed the app, so it merely seems to work... until another user tries to use it (and they end up impersonating you).**

1. Go to your App's management page. Select "OAuth & Permissions".
2. Add the `chat.write` OAuth Scope to your app as a **User** Token Scope, not a **Bot** Token scope.
3. Take note of your `User OAuth Token` at the top of this page (**not** your `But User OAuth Token`).
4. Call `chat.postMessage` with

   - `username` = user id of the user you'd like to post on behalf of
   - `token` = the token from step 3. above

The resulting post will be 100% impersonated. Not just the name and icon as mentioned in other answers, but it'll 100% function as if it came from the user.

Comment: Hi V Maharaj , Using this I'm able to send message on nehalf of myself but even if I add a user id in for other  users it still sends a message on my behalf. Do I need to get user auth tokens for all users in the slack channel? If yes, how do I get those? I used the following snippet but it always sends messages on my behalf.

url = "https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage"

 payload = json.dumps(
  {
   "channel": channel,
   "text": message,
   "thread_ts": time_stamp,
   "username": user_id
  })

Comment: Yeah it doesn't work. See the UPDATE: at the top of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will help those who are still facing this issue.

1. First give the `chat:write` and `chat:write.customize` scope to your bot. The scope `chat:write.customize` Send messages as @your_slack_app with a customized username and avatar
2. From "OAuth & Permissions" settings get the bot OAuth token or even bot access token (both will work).
3. Then set the arguments like the following.

`username` to specify the username for the published message.

`icon_url` to specify a URL to an image to use as the profile photo alongside the message.

`icon_emoji` to specify an emoji (using colon shortcodes, eg. :white_check_mark:) to use as the profile photo alongside the message.

You can visit the docs from [here](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#authorship)

Comment: Hi @Barun, Your answer worked for me but in the notifications the word bot is added in front of the name. Is there a way to remove that word from notifications o update the name displayed in notifications

Comment: For example when I use this to send a message the notification shows the name as mentioned in the username key but if I send a message in a thread, the name shown in notifications is '{username} (bot)'