# Post Slack message as specific user

Tags: slack-api, giphy

I'm building a Slack bot with slash commands and I would like to post a message **with an attachment** as a specific user (specifically, the user that called the slash command).

I know this is possible because the Giphy Slack integration does so when responding to the `/giphy [image]` command, by responding [*as the user* with a gif image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdGAj.png).

- I tried using the [`chat.meMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.meMessage) method but this does not appear to support attachments.
- I tried using the `as_user` argument in the [`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) method, but this inherits the *authenticated* user rather than the user that called the slash command.
- Responding to the slash command immediately or performing a delayed response (using `response_url`) doesn't seem to support non-bot responses. If they do, I can't seem to find where it's documented.

In the slash request Slack does provide both `user_id` and `user_name` parameters, so I imagine I can make use of those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reached out to Slack with this question, and unfortunately at this time it doesn't look like what I'm asking for is possible. The Giphy Slack integration was internally built.

Maybe in the future!

Comment: Correct, that is not possible. but you can "fake" the user name and icon of a message. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42658126/is-it-possible-to-post-to-chat-postmessage-as-any-user-in-a-slack-team?rq=1) answer for details. Its no perfect thought, since it will still show as "bot".