# Send slack message as any username

Tags: bots, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to create a new integration to combine slack with another chat system.
If someone sends a message from skype for example, I want his name to be used when the message is sent to slack. Right now I'm using IncomingWebhook to send messages.

```
private getWebClient(configuration: ConfigurationData): IncomingWebhook {
    return new IncomingWebhook('https://hooks.slack.com/services/...');
}

const webhook = this.getWebClient(configuration);
await webhook.send(
    {
        text: 'How are you today?',
        as_user: false,
        username: 'slack_integration',
        icon_emoji: ':chart_with_upwards_trend:',
        thread_ts: event.ts
    }
);
```

As you can see, I'm also trying to reply to the message in a thread. This is not working either. The following event I get looks as follows:

```
{ text: 'How are you today?',
  bot_id: 'B9G8LHME1',
  type: 'message',
  subtype: 'bot_message',
  ts: '1519830326.000061',
  channel: 'C9G4BJ8BW',
  event_ts: '1519830326.000061' }
```

The message still appears to be from my App. The name is "Slack Integration Test" (with a badge showing `App` right next to it).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to post to chat.postMessage as any user in a Slack team?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42658126/is-it-possible-to-post-to-chat-postmessage-as-any-user-in-a-slack-team)

Comment: works similar to incoming webhooks

Comment: I'm following the instructions there but It doesn't help