# slack incoming webhook always posting to default channel even though I give different channel

Tags: slack-api

I am trying to send messages to slack channel using incoming webhooks and the webhook is created with default channel as #channel1 but now I want to send message to channel #general using the same incoming webhook

and I am using the following command to do that

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{ "channel": "#general", "text":"Sample Message!"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXX
```

However, it still sends the message to #channel1 , ignoring the channel name I gave #general.

Any suggestions as to why or am I missing some setting some where?

Answer (score 4):

If you create a webhook through a Slack app the channel is static and can not be overridden by including a `channel` property in the request.

If you want to use the channel override feature you need to create a webhook through the legacy "Incoming Webhook" app, which you can install from the Slack App Directory.

You can also read more about this legacy feature [here](https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/incoming-webhooks).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51878825/slack-incoming-webhook-sends-as-my-user/51884185#51884185).